# Using non before compound word

Tags: word-choice, negation

I have the word `peer-reviewed`. I need to use non before it. Is it:

> non-peer-reviewed

Or

> non-peer reviewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-peer-reviewed. We join 'non' to adjectives with a hyphen: non-flammable, non-greasy, non-returnable. If the adjective is itself a hyphenated compound, this is still true.